[Delete all rows that don't contain (color Orange 44) in cell in worksheet
I want delete Row if Colorindex <> 44 in Cells Range("C9:F303","F9:M303")
Sub Delete_line_if_no_color_44()
    Dim NbreLigneMax As Long
    NbreLigneMax = cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = NbreLigneMax To 9 Step -1
       If Range("F" & i).Interior.ColorIndex <> 44 And Range("M" & i).Interior.ColorIndex <> 44 Then
           Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
       End If
   Next
End Sub


Range("C9:F303","F9:M303") this is the real range where you want to check to background color? This is in real Range("C9:M303") . Your code now checks only for columns FandM`

In other words. you want to keep a row if any cell in columns C to M is Orange. Is this correct ?

Use nested loop to validate all cells from Col C to Col M.
Sub Delete_line_if_no_color_44()
    Dim NbreLigneMax As Long, bHasColorCell As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Const START_COL = 3 ' Col C, modify as needed
    Const END_COL = 13 ' Col M
    Const COLOR_IND = 44
    NbreLigneMax = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = NbreLigneMax To 9 Step -1
        bHasColorCell = False
        For j = START_COL To END_COL
            If Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = COLOR_IND Then
                bHasColorCell = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        If Not bHasColorCell Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

